# Android-sdk emulator doesn't work

Tags: android, emulation

My platform: debian 8 (sid)

uname -a : Linux ... 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.78-1 i686 GNU/Linux

I downloaded android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz from https://developer.android.com/
but emulator(*) executables don't run because I get :

"bash: tools/emulator: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error. "

I guess this means these binaries can't run on my system. So does it mean , I can't run the emulator on my platform?

I didn't find source of emulator in tgz.

Or where can I find the source of emulator?
thanks

Comment: You should be able to install the Android tools from apt-get

Comment: Could you tell me which package does contain the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Hehe....
If I downloaded tgz file with wget (wget  http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz), binaries work!
I don't understand why.... ?.... :-|

Comment: you were getting an exec format error, not a file not found. So the binaries existed before, they were just corrupted

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work ! :(

This was very strange for me.

When I downloaded tgz and extracted, the binaries worked.

I run SDK manager and downloaded some packages for example : some System Images, Android 6.0 SDK platform, build tools, etc, and after this, binaries didn't work.

I figured it out, the case of problem was I updated current SDK tools. After update The binaries didn't work.